# ofstream not properly naming created files

Tags: c++, ofstream

this does create a file like i want but instead of the input name it just calls it fileName and it doesn't have a type. Its supposed to take an input of something like "story.txt" and create a text file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string userInput;
    string endWrite = "** STOP **";
    string fileName = "";

    cin >> fileName;

    ofstream storyTime(fileName.c_str());

    storyTime.open("fileName");
    if (!storyTime.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open file " << fileName << "." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    getline(cin, userInput);


    while (userInput != endWrite) {
        storyTime << userInput << endl;

        getline(cin, userInput);
    }
    storyTime.close();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ofstream storyTime(fileName.c_str());` should already open the file so `storyTime.open("fileName");` is not wanted.

Comment: My guess is you are looking in the wrong location for the file.

Comment: @drescherjm oh thank you. I'll try deleting that

Comment: The documentation for open [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/) states ***If the stream is already associated with a file (i.e., it is already open), calling this function fails.*** so your second attempt to open a file with the name "fileName" will fail.

Comment: @ drescherjm hmmm its still just naming the file fileName without a type

Comment: If you deleted `storyTime.open("fileName");` it should name the file whatever you typed in when the program started in `cin >> fileName;` Did you type story.txt and hit enter? Note that your program does not tell the user to enter a filename or anything it just expects input.

Comment: @ drescherjm yeah i deleted that line but its still not properly creating files on my computer. it is partially working now in our interactive text book though.

Comment: My only guess is you are no running the code you think you are. Perhaps the current code did not compile and you are still running the old executable.